# Where is JAVA_HOME expanded to JAVA_HOME/jre?

Tags: tomcat, debian-jessie, jdk

We have a Tomcat 8 running on Debian 8/jessie.

When starting the tomcat using `service tomcat8 start` we can see
    INFO: Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre

In `/etc/default/tomcat8` we have set

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
```

In `/etc/init.d/tomcat8` is `JAVA_HOME` not set set explicity. Neither in `setenv.sh`.
The environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is not set.

Background: We have problems with compiling JSP files as the Tomcat can not find the java compiler. We suspect the wrong path for `JAVA_HOME? as it points only to the jre.

**Where is `JAVA_HOME` expanded to `JAVA_HOME/jre`?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting exactly what your problem is, but think that you couldn't set `JAVA_HOME` variable properly somehow, So, I will answer assuming this fact.

#### Adding to `/etc/profile`

1. Open **`/etc/profile`** in any text editor & add the following line :

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/Path/to/Java/home/directory"
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

   where path in your case is `usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`
2. Now, **`source`** the profile file to load the variables :

   ```
   source /etc/profile
   ```

#### Adding to `/etc/environment`

You can set your `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/profile`, but the preferred location for `JAVA_HOME` or any system variable is `/etc/environment`.

1. Open **`/etc/environment`** in any text editor & add the following line :

   ```
   JAVA_HOME="/Path/to/Java/home/directory"
   export JAVA_HOME
   ```

   And path in your case is `usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`
2. Now, **`source`** the environment file to load the variables :

   ```
   . /etc/environment
   ```
3. Check the variable being set or not, by echoing it :

   ```
   echo $JAVA_HOME
   ```

`NOTE` : Usually most linux systems source `/etc/environment` by default, However, If your system doesn't do that add the following line to `~/.bashrc`.

```
source /etc/environment
```

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We have problems with compiling JSP files as the Tomcat can not find the java compiler. We suspect the wrong path for JAVA_HOME as it points _only_ to the jre.

Comment: In that case, you should write an answer on your own, stating root cause and the solution. That would help community !

Comment: I will as soon as we have found a solution. :-) At the moment were are stack with the problem stated above in the question. I will try your answer and see if it helps. :-)